# Graph API wont display profile feed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook API to get my wall feed using the graph API.

```
<?php
    require_once('facebook.php');

//  Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '188687744521977',
    'secret' => 'c2c3692845602812f473436d1da95014',
    'cookie' => true
));

//  Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//  We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//  If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
//  Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
//  token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if($user) 
{
    try 
    {
//          Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_188687744521977_access_token'];
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $likes = $facebook->api('/me?fields=feed,likes');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
        $feed = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?  access_token='.$access_token.'';
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

//  Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if($user) 
{
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else 
{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

//  Save the user's info as variables
$full_name = $user_profile['name'];
$first_name = $user_profile['first_name'];
$last_name = $user_profile['last_name'];

$relationship = $user_profile['relationship_status'];
$partner_id = $user_profile['significant_other_id'];

$id = $user_profile['id'];
$link = $user_profile['link'];

function get_url($url)
{
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        $tmp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $tmp;
}

$wall = get_url($feed);
print_r(json_decode($wall, true));
?>
```

However, an empty array is displayed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitly try to find a better solution for handling the access token! Where are you setting this `$_SESSION['fb_..._access_token']`? Who says that 188687744521977 is always the userid of the logged in user? Why do you have spaces in your feed url?

The first thing you should do is delete the `json_decode()` and just `var_dump()` the `$wall`. I think your access token is not valid, maybe you also get a 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden response?

Comment: No, actually I'm not getting a 401 or a 403 message. And the number is the ID of the application, not the user. That number is static.